# ApplicationPath on Application_Start

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been trying to get the application path for my project on the Application_Start event in the global asax I can use server.mappath on pages that aren't routed but when i am on a routed page i get the new virtual path is there a way of getting the application path on startup i can't use Request or session or HttpContext.items[key] at that level does anyone know what to do

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the solution:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.aspx

Comment: That is my answer but when I do this HostinEnvironment.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\App_GlobalResources" i get the double backslash

Comment: I don't understand, first of all, to combine differents path use System.IO.Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.PhysicalApplicationPath, "App_GlobalResources"); and not contact

Comment: Its my mistake i was concentrating on the path it returned correctly

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use Application_BeginRequest to map path everytime?

There you can use

```
HttpApplication.Request.RawUrl
```

to get the requested path and later you can rewrite it with mapped path using

```
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath
```